When to use paired samples tests? Specific case in clinical research
I am working on the analysis of an observational clinical study. It is basically a control/intervention study, where the intervention group received a novel protocol. In order to assess its effectiveness, a control group was found using a least squares algorithm to find, for each intervention patient, a similar control that did not receive the protocol.
At the end, the connection between intervention and control is just a similarity that we force to evaluate the impact of the protocol.
If we perform different statistical tests: do we have to treat the samples as if they were paired? Or is it enough to say that the pairing (based on least squares) was just to ensure general similarity between samples and we can use independent tests?
Additionally, if you have any thoughts or criticism about the described method, feel free to share them.

Plenty of previous questions on the paired vs. non-paired topic: here, here and here.

The problem is that I don't see a general agreement. While I read a lot that there is no natural pairing in (similarity-based) matched data, other authors disagree. Quote: "... we should use the differences between individually matched cases and their controls. Appropriate simple methods include the paired t test for means..." (source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2541945/).

Given that this is a clinical study I presume that a design for it was put before an institutional review committee of some sort. That design should have included the method of analysis, along with sample size determination. Use that design.

Thanks for the suggestion. However, my interest here is beyond the design of this specific case. What is the correct, or the most common approach in such situations?
